# Stale data with StimulusJS and Quill editor

Tags: quill, stimulusjs

I am integrating the Quill editor with Rails and would like to control it with [StimulusJS](https://github.com/stimulusjs/stimulus). Essentially I have a field on a Rails form, which has html stored in it, and it becomes and Quill rich text editor. There are also 2 other field consuming data from Quill: plain text (stripped of tags) and deltas (changes log).

All three are then saved to the db via the usual form submit.

It is *almost* working.

The form and controller code

```
<div data-controller='quill'>
      <%= f.input :target_note,
            input_html: {
              data: {
                target: 'quill.editor',
                action: "keyup->quill#update" } } %>
      <input data-target='quill.delta'/>
      <input data-target='quill.text' />
    </div>
```

The Stimulus controller

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['editor','delta','text'];

  connect() {
    console.log('connected');
    this.quill = new Quill('#grammar_note_target_note', {
      theme: 'snow'
    });
  }

  update(){
    console.log(this.quill.getContents());
    console.log(this.quill.getText());
    this.textTarget.value = this.quill.getText();
    this.deltaTarget.value = this.quill.getContents();
  }
}
```

**Problem**

When the user types into the editor field, the data that was previously saved is copied as delta / plain text to the textTarget and deltaTarget fields. In the image below, the value of 'asdasdasdsa' was previously saved into the field, while the user just typed 'hhh'.

**Expected behaviour**

On every keystroke, the actual text would be transformed into deltas or text and stored in the 2 fields.

Any help would really be appreciated. :grin:

### Edit

@jhchen every keystroke produces the same, original data that was in the field. The changes are reflected on screen, but not in the 2 inputs or console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a delay issue ('hhh' was pasted or typed quickly) or did you type hhh slowly one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it all working, but am not 100% sold on StimulusJS. There is possibly a better way to do this, but this is my solution:

**javascript**

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['editor','html','text'];

  initialize() {
    this.quill = new Quill(this.editorTarget, {
      theme: 'snow'
    });
    this.quill.on("text-change", e => {
      this.textChange();
    });
 }

 textChange(){
    this.htmlTarget.value = this.quill.root.innerHTML;
    this.textTarget.value = this.quill.getText();
 }
```

}

**view**

```
<div data-controller='quill'>
    <div data-target='quill.editor'>
      <% if f.object.target_note.present? %>
        <%= f.object.target_note.html_safe %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :target_note,
          label: false,
          input_html: {
            class: 'display-none',
            data: { target: 'quill.html' } } %>
    <%= f.input :target_note_text,
          label: false,
          input_html: {
            class: 'display-none',
            data: { target: 'quill.text' }
          } %>
  </div>
```

The `display-none` class and `label: false` where needed as StimulusJS cannot target a hidden field !!!

Comment: I have the following hidden field `<input data-target="hello.id" type="hidden" value="1" name="event[id]" id="event_id">` and I have no problem using a Stimulus target to get this field value.

`this.idTarget.value` works fine for me

Comment: Thanks @Adrien that's interesting. In this case it was hidden via css class.